# Forecast survey response rate

Tags: bayesian, forecasting, monte-carlo, pymc

I am new to Bayesian forecasting and hope you can help me get started with this problem:

**I need to forecast the likely survey response rate to a paid-for survey**

Background information:

- Each person is paid for participating, so we don't want to contact more people than we need to
- Each person has up to 30 days to take part
- Based on historical surveys only about 50% of people will respond but it varies from about 35% to 65%
- Of those who do respond, 20% do so on the same day, after which the response rate rapidly reduces

Here is a graph of the typical response curve (of the 50% who do respond):
[image]

One other important point: We do not contact all people on the same day! Typically we have a weekly mailshot over 4 weeks. Therefore, at any one time, we could have people from this week, last week and the week before.

So here is my question:

- Using the prior and based on the responses we see so far for each mailshot, can we predict the final response rate??
- We have the prior (50%)
- We have the mailshot1 response rate (now at day 22)
- We have the mailshot2 response rate (now at day 15)
- We have the mailshot3 response rate (now at day 2)
- We have not yet sent the 4th mailshot and I want to adjust the size of this mailshot based on the forecast

I have done a ton of online reading and bought a few books but I cannot figure out where to start with this problem because I need to combine the results of each mailshot, none of which have completed the full 30 days yet.

I am using jupyter, PyMC3 and scipy if that helps.

If you could just get me started, that would be a huge help.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have any predictive features you can associate with the individuals who have been contacted, other than whether and when they have responded?

Comment: I do... mainly based on whether they have responded in the past and whether we sent a reminder email. They both have a positive effect. However, right now I am just trying to solve the simpler question ignoring any other predictive features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to do survival analysis and use a [Cox model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model) to predict the probability that each individual already contacted will "survive" 30 days without responding, then subtract those predicted probabilities from 1 (with 0s for all the people who've already replied) and sum the results to get an estimate of the eventual response rate. In this model, a survey response would be the event of interest, and observation for individuals who don't respond would be right-censored at 30 days. If you wanted to get really technical, you might consider a [split-population model](https://rjournal.github.io/archive/2017/RJ-2017-056/RJ-2017-056.pdf) to better accommodate the fact that a substantial proportion of your units of observation never experience the "failure" event (i.e., never respond).

One advantage of the survival-analysis approach would be the ability to use individual-level covariates (e.g., sex, age, response history) to improve your predictions, if you have those in your data. Another would be the ability to take advantage of the information you have about responses (or lack thereof) so far across the ongoing mailshots, i.e., to look at the probabilities conditional on survival to time *t*. Together, those aspects would probably allow you to improve upon the simple (but not bad!) base-rate estimate you have now as your prior.

One potential obstacle is the need for comparable data from one or more completed previous surveys to use in fitting the model. You would want completed surveys instead of just using the data you have so far from the current survey because you want to include a representative pool of right-censored cases.

If you have data from prior surveys, you could also take an empirical Bayesian approach to estimating those probabilities. For each time step from 1 to 30, you could compute the fractions of eventual respondents and non-respondents, conditional on having not responded until that time. You could then use Bayes' rule to take those fractions and update your prior for each individual who hasn't yet responded, given their current time step, and then sum those updated probabilities to get your final estimate. This would add information about time from the ongoing survey, but it wouldn't use information about specific individuals (if you have it).

Here's how that second approach would work in practice. Let's say you want to estimate the probability that someone who hasn't responded after 15 days--the non-respondents so far in your mailshot 2--will respond before the 30-day window closes. Your data from previous surveys show that 50% of targeted individuals respond overall, and that 70% of the individuals who do respond will do so within the first 15 days. So...

- your prior, or p(A), is 0.5;
- the probability of observing a non-response after 15 days for someone who will never respond, or p(B|not A), is, of course, 1; and
- the probability of observing a non-response after 15 days for someone who *will* eventually respond, or p(B|A), can be estimated as the fraction of respondents in previous surveys who replied on days 16-30, which is 1 - 0.7, or 0.3.

Now plug those quantities into Bayes' rule...

```
(0.5 * 0.3) / [(0.5 * 0.3) + (1 * (1 - 0.5))] = 0.15 / (0.15 + 0.5) = 0.23
```

So, for all the individuals in mailshot 2 who have not yet responded, you would assign a probability of eventually responding of 0.23. If there were 100 individuals in that pool, and 30 have responded so far, you would add 0.23 * 70, or 16.1, to that 30 to arrive at a final estimate of 46.1 eventual respondents for that pool. Repeat for the other mailshots, then sum the results, and you get to a posterior estimate of the eventual response count for the mailshots in progress that updates your base-rate prior based on what you've seen so far.

Comment: Thank you @ulfelder! That is a brilliant starting point for me and sounds ideally suited. I will work on this over the next few days. If you have any particularly good references I could read please let me know. Thank you again!